# reducing redundant product from SQL cross join

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join, redundancy

I was stepping through a common SQL exercise and ran into an annoyance.  Question is whether you have a better solve than mine below.  The initial problem was "find all the coordinate sets on a plain that have the shortest overall distance."  That's straightforward.  However, when you select all those rows that have the shortest distance, you get (for example):

| x | y | x2 | y2 | dist | globalmin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 0 | -1 | -2 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |
| -2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |
| -1 | -2 | -2 | 0 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |
| 0 | 1 | -2 | 0 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |

You see the problem -- I'm pulling redundant rows because an earlier cross join has mirrored the x and y the values.

The solution I found was to to distinct a least, greatest swap like so:

```
select
distinct
least(t1.x,t1.x2) x1, greatest(t1.x,t1.x2) x2, least(t1.y,t1.y2) y1, greatest(t1.y,t1.y2) y2
,dist,globalmin
from dists2 t1
where t1.dist=t1.globalmin
;
```

Result:

| x1 | x2 | y1 | y2 | dist | globalmin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | -1 | -2 | 0 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |
| -2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2.23606797749979 | 2.23606797749979 |

...so that approach will fix the redundancy issue, but it feels inelegant, like there's a classic maneuver I'm missing.  I welcome any advice on a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Original sample data and query would help (the bit that made that table at the top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have 2 distinct points `A` and `B`, your query says:

- Give me the distance from the top/left point to the bottom/right point (i.e. the distance from e.g. `A` to `B`).
- Also give me the distance from the bottom/right point to the top/left point (i.e. the opposite of the above = distance from `B` to `A`).

Armed with that knowledge, all we have to do is create an order between points. One case that would work:

- If `A` is left of `B` (`A.x < B.x`), then `A < B`.
- If `A` is placed on a vertical line that goes through `B` (`A.x = B.x`) and is above `B` (`A.y < B.y`), then `A < B`.
  Note: not that it matters but for `A` to be said to be *above* `B`, the y axis must be oriented down.
- In every other case, `A >= B`.

You can show that it is indeed an [order relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Basic_definitions) (to be precise, a [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)), although the way I described it makes it a strict order (no points is "before" itself).
Also, the set of points is not just partially ordered: every pair of points can be compared. It is said to be [totally ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Now that we have a way to order every point against every other point, we can work with a **non-equi join**.

---

Quick example: the query below works on 4 points placed on the 4 corners of a square.

- The point of coordinates `(0,0)` is ordered before the other 3 points, so it is joined against them all.
- The points of coordinates `(0,1)` is ordered before the 2 points on its right but not before `(0,0)`, as the latter is placed vertically and above the former.
- The point of coordinates `(1,0)` is only ordered before `(1,1)`, which is placed vertically to it, but under it.

```sql
WITH Points(x, y) AS (
VALUES (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)
)
SELECT p1.x as x1, p1.y as y1, p2.x as x2, p2.y as y2
FROM Points p1
JOIN Points p2 ON p1.x < p2.x OR (p1.x = p2.x AND p1.y < p2.y)
ORDER BY x1, y1, x2, y2
```

---

From there, it is easy to turn a `point_table p1 CROSS JOIN point_table p2` into the proper `point_table p1 INNER JOIN point_table p2 ON ...` on the model shown above.
However, contrary to your question title, you seem to have a single `dists2`  table/view.

- If it is a view, change its definition by replacing the `CROSS JOIN` by an `INNER JOIN` just like I said.
- If it is a table, the condition we have seen in the `ON` clause must be moved to a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT x1, x2, y1, y2 ,dist,globalmin
FROM dists2
WHERE x1 < x2 OR (x1 = x2 AND y1 < y2)
AND dist=globalmin
```